# Type of generic type in function signature

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a generic function where I would like to have an argument of a type of other generic parameter. Here is a code sample:

```
function find<K,V,P extends keyof V>(map: Map<K,V>, property: P, value: number): boolean {
  for (const entry of Array.from(map.values())) {
    if (entry[property] == value)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

let map = new Map<string, string>([["a", "test"]]);
const result: boolean = find<string,string,'length'>(map, 'length', 4); //is the entry 'a' of length 4 ?
```

This doesn't work since the type of `value: number` is hard-coded. I would like to be it the type of `property:P` in the `V` type. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types)

```
function find<K,V,P extends keyof V>(map: Map<K,V>, property: P, value: V[P])
```